# looping through the values of an ArrayList in C#

Tags: c#, arraylist, osc

I'm trying to figure out what sort of information these messages contain that are being streamed via OSC. The messages are being stored to an ArrayList. Here is the code:

```
public void OSCMessageReceived(OSC.NET.OSCMessage message){ 
        string address = message.Address;
        ArrayList args = message.Values;
}
```

How do I loop through the values of the arrayList args to output its contents?

Comment: `foreach(Object o in args)Console.WriteLine(o);`

Comment: Note: `ArrayList` is the old non-generic variant of `List<T>` and can be used much like `List<T>`, except that the items are typed as `object`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can try with this code

```
foreach(var item in args )
{
  Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a simple `for` loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < args.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(args[i].ToString());
}
```

Check out [this link here](http://csharp.net-informations.com/collection/csharp-arraylist.htm) for more info on the C# ArrayList object.

Answer (score 3):

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList(new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" });
foreach (var item in al)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

You can also use a `for` loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < al.Count; ++i)
{
    Console.WriteLine(al[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know the type of objects in the ArrayList, your only option is to call the `ToString()` method on each item.

If you do know the type of objects, you can cast them to the appropriate type and then to print the content in a more intelligent way.

Answer (score -1):

Both **foreach()** and **for(int i = 0;...)** scroll through all entries of the ArrayList. However it seems that **foreach()** scrolls through them in the order in which they were added to the ArrayList. With **for(int i = 0;...)** I observed (Visual Studio 2005) that this is not necessarily true. I experienced in one case that when the objects added to the ArrayList were simple **int**'s it was the case. However when the added objects were of a complex class type the scroll order no longer corresponded to the order in which they had been added to the ArrayList.

Comment: The two methods are equivalent and should never result in different ordering?